# What syntax am I not seeing or entering correctly via python?

Tags: python, syntax, pygame

I've been learning Python the easy (for me) way: simple video game example tutorials from sentdex on youtube. The concepts which I had not already known are made much clearer in the context of something for which I see value like a simple game. Anyway, I have come to an issue; for some reason, I cannot get a menu page to blit. I originally followed the tutorial very closely, with an eye for punctuation, capitalization and proper indentation as I see that seems to be the n00bs most consistent pitfall. However, the tutorial did not work for that section, and the program goes right into the game loop, even when game over. I have tried other methods prescribed throughout here, google, and youtube, but nothing seems to be working! I get a non-descriptive "syntax error", but as far as I can tell, the vital bits are wired up right. I'm sure I'm just being a blind noob, but some simple analysis would be much appreciated on this code!

NOTE: I know I have some danglers like how I imported Pickle but haven't used it yet, those are all just reminders for the next steps, soon to be fleshed out as soon as this menu problem is resolved.

Running python (with pygame) 2.7, since I cant get pygame to work on python 3.
I have both Eric5 and pycharm, I am running Debian Jessie with a backported Cinnamon (And I believe the kernel to, but I might be wrong)

```
    #!/urs/bin/python2.7

import random
import pygame
import time
##import pickle

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zoomin' Zigs")

#Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#asset variables
carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
car_width = 142
car_height = 100
background = pygame.image.load('road.png')
smbarricade = pygame.image.load('barricade_166x83.png')
menuimage = pygame.image.load('menu.png')
##lgbarricade = pygame.image.load()
menuactive = True

#FUNCTIONS
##def blocks (blockx, blocky,  blockw,  blockh,  color):
##    pygame.draw.rect(gamewindow,  color,  [blockx,  blocky,  blockw,  blockh, ])


##def leftclick():
##    
##    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
##                mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() and leftclick = True
##                
def smbarricades (smbar_startx,  smbar_starty):
    gamedisplay.blit(smbarricade,  (smbar_startx,  smbar_starty))

def car(x, y):
    gamedisplay.blit(carImg,  (x, y))

def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    menuscreen()

def button(x, y, w, h,):
    mousecoords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if  x+w > mousecoords[0] > x and y+h . mousecoords[1] >y:
        pygame.Rect(gamedisplay (x, y, w, h))


def text_objects(text,  font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface,  textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text): 
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',  115)
    TextSurf,  TextRect = text_objects(text,  largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),  (display_height/2))
    gamedisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def button(x, y, w, h,):
    if  x+w > mousecoords[0] > x and y+h > mousecoords[1] >y:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

def dodge_count(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,  25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count),  True,  blue)
    gamedisplay.blit(text,  (30,100))


################################MENU###################################################


def menuscreen():



    ##mousecoords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    ##playbX = 6
    ##playbY = 107
    ##playbutton_rect = pygame.Rect(playbx,  playby,  115,  40)
    ##exitbX = 634
    ##exitbY = 514
    ##exitbutton = pygame.Rect(exitbx,  exitby,  120,  60)
   ## exitb_rect = pygame.Rect(exitbx,  exitby,  120,  60)   



    while menuactive:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            else:
                time.sleep(3)
                game_loop()

        gamedisplay.blit(menuimage (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)







################################GAME#LOOP###############################################
def game_loop():


    #CAR attributes/variables
    x = (display_width * 0.3725)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)
    x_change = 0

    #SMBARRICADE attributes/variables
    smbar_starty = -83
    smbar_speed = 5
    smbarStartXA = 147
    smbarStartXB = 444
    smbar_startx =  random.choice ((smbarStartXA, smbarStartXB))
    smbar_width = 166
    smbar_height = 83

    dodged = 0

    while not menuactive:




        for event in pygame.event.get():


            # GAME QUIT  EVENT
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()

            #CAR CONTROL LOOP
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -7
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 7
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

            print(event)        

        x += x_change

        gamedisplay.blit(background,  (0, 0))


        smbarricades (smbar_startx,  smbar_starty)
        smbar_starty += smbar_speed
        car(x, y)
        dodge_count(dodged)


        #OBSTACLE RENEWAL
        if smbar_starty > display_height:
            smbar_starty = -83
            smbar_startx =  random.choice ((smbarStartXA,  smbarStartXB))
            #DODGE COUNT
            dodged += 1


        #CRASHESloop
        if y <= smbar_starty+smbar_height and y >= smbar_starty+smbar_height and x <= smbar_startx+car_width and x >= smbar_startx-car_width:
            crash()
            menuactive = True



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
  ########################################################################################  

menuscreen()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: `if  x+w > mousecoords[0] > x and y+h . mousecoords[1] >y:` This line probably causes it. No idea what you meant with that dot after `y+h`.

Comment: Also, when asking question, please provide full error message. Don't just say SyntaxError.

Comment: you had defined `button()` function twice in your program.

Comment: that fixed it slightly. now it crashes trying to blit the png image I am attempting to use as a background. I use GIMP alot, and with GIMP I can click with the scroll wheel to grab and drag the screen, so now I do it without even noticing, but in eric5, every time I do that it inserts some snippet of code from elsewhere in the document and I dont even notice, I dont believe I had any plans for the mouse thing... and sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: Just a reminder that we all have to start somewhere, and there's a [distinction between noob and newb](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Noobs%20vs.%20Newbs). Other than that you have `button()` defined twice, as noticed by @anandtripathi, and the first definition has a syntax error (as pointed by @Lafexlos. If you read the whole error you will probably get a hint at the line where the error occurs.

Comment: can you please provide what syntax error you are getting?

Comment: @berna1111 FWIW, that's not a good link for n00b vs newb distinction. The author comes over as a complete and utter tw*t, I'd not trust him to clean my drains let alone educate me on the nuances of internet conversations.

Comment: @Ben can you show me the image that you used cause i ran the code that is below its working but i used the dummy images  i want your image and want to see how the game works like.Thanks

Comment: Don't post your whole code here, make an [mcve] by removing unnecessary parts (things that don't contribute to the error) until the program contains as little code as possible and the error. Most likely you'll find the error by yourself. If not, you'll at least have made it easier for us to find the problem. Going through 100+ lines of code to find errors isn't easy just because someone have more knowledge about the language/library. Some people might answer anyway (I used too) but it consumes much time and it doesn't take long before they are burned out.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the info. It has been less angry than some of the noob questions ive asked in other stackexchange sites. the fixed code in the answer is great for me to learn from because I learn well from reverse engineering, and all the comments have built on that info and expanded my knowledge base.

Comment: @berna 1111 thank you for the tips and the positivity! using  your tips and Ted Klein Bergman's tips I discovered the issue was because of a missing comma in a blit command's tuple.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman thank you for not being to harsh on me, see I just wanted to be thorough and include all the information I could, as I am new enough I wasn't sure how much of the code needed to be added, and other posts I have seen had comments asking for more code. Also I very much appreciate the mini breakdown of debugging/posting code. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben I understand your concerns. Just remember that information that isn't relevant to the problem shadows it rather than revealing it. So, sometimes it's best to not include all information you can. It is often hard to determine what information to include but if you create a [mcve] it's almost *impossible* that you've include too little information (unless the error isn't caused by the code). The other questions were people have commented _"We need more code"_ doesn't include [mcve]. They've just copy and pasted a small section of their code.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I think I'm beginning to really understand the mindset of the community; In my viewing of random python videos on youtube yesterday, I cam across many from the developers, and seeing something like "Beyond PEP8" shows me how *exacting*  and efficient in even the minutia one is required to be by a Programmer (capital "P"), as if I'm talking with Germans! Refreshing. Indeed I'm just overwhelmed right now, although I think that copious amounts of stimulants and a several-day long crash course I am beginning to grasp the fundamentals and key terminology, at least to some degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I saw your code and did necessary changes And **Its Working now** next time kindly provide us the whole details.

```
#!/urs/bin/python2.7

import random
import pygame
import time
# import pickle


menuactive = True
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zoomin' Zigs")

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# asset variables
carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
car_width = 142
car_height = 100
background = pygame.image.load('road.png')
smbarricade = pygame.image.load('barricade_166x83.png')
menuimage = pygame.image.load('menu.png')
##lgbarricade = pygame.image.load()


# FUNCTIONS
# def blocks (blockx, blocky,  blockw,  blockh,  color):
##    pygame.draw.rect(gamewindow,  color,  [blockx,  blocky,  blockw,  blockh, ])


# def leftclick():
##
# if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
# mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() and leftclick = True
##
def smbarricades(smbar_startx,  smbar_starty):
    gamedisplay.blit(smbarricade,  (smbar_startx,  smbar_starty))


def car(x, y):
    gamedisplay.blit(carImg,  (x, y))


def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')
    pygame.display.update()
    # menuscreen()

# def button(x, y, w, h,):
#     mousecoords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
#     if  x+w > mousecoords[0] > x and y+h . mousecoords[1] >y:
#         pygame.Rect(gamedisplay (x, y, w, h))


def text_objects(text,  font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface,  textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',  115)
    TextSurf,  TextRect = text_objects(text,  largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2),  (display_height / 2))
    gamedisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


def button(x, y, w, h,):
    mousecoords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if x + w > mousecoords[0] > x and y + h > mousecoords[1] > y:
        # pygame.quit()
        # quit()
        global menuactive
        menuactive = False


def dodge_count(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,  25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count),  True,  blue)
    gamedisplay.blit(text,  (30, 100))


################################MENU######################################


def menuscreen():

    ##mousecoords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    ##playbX = 6
    ##playbY = 107
    ##playbutton_rect = pygame.Rect(playbx,  playby,  115,  40)
    ##exitbX = 634
    ##exitbY = 514
    ##exitbutton = pygame.Rect(exitbx,  exitby,  120,  60)
   ## exitb_rect = pygame.Rect(exitbx,  exitby,  120,  60)

    global menuactive
    while menuactive:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print event
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                menuactive = False
            else:
                # time.sleep(3)
                game_loop()

        gamedisplay.blit(menuimage, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


################################GAME#LOOP#################################
def game_loop():

    # CAR attributes/variables
    x = (display_width * 0.3725)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)
    x_change = 0

    # SMBARRICADE attributes/variables
    smbar_starty = -83
    smbar_speed = 5
    smbarStartXA = 147
    smbarStartXB = 444
    smbar_startx = random.choice((smbarStartXA, smbarStartXB))
    smbar_width = 166
    smbar_height = 83

    dodged = 0
    global menuactive
    while menuactive:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # pygame.quit()
                menuactive = False

            # CAR CONTROL LOOP
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -7
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 7
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

            print(event)

        x += x_change

        gamedisplay.blit(background,  (0, 0))

        smbarricades(smbar_startx,  smbar_starty)
        smbar_starty += smbar_speed
        car(x, y)
        dodge_count(dodged)

        # OBSTACLE RENEWAL
        if smbar_starty > display_height:
            smbar_starty = -83
            smbar_startx = random.choice((smbarStartXA,  smbarStartXB))
            # DODGE COUNT
            dodged += 1

        # CRASHESloop
        if y <= smbar_starty + smbar_height and y >= smbar_starty + smbar_height and x <= smbar_startx + car_width and x >= smbar_startx - car_width:
            crash()
            menuactive = False

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
  ##########################################################################


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    menuscreen()
    # game_loop()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!, I am seeing more and more reading other posts on this site that it is indeed rare to have someone actually fix your code for you! I wish to express profound gratitude to you!